# iPhone App rejected due to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: iphone, app-store, info-plist

This is twice that I am getting this message from apple for the reason of rejection.

---

From `Apple`

2.3 - Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected

2.3 Details

We attempted to review your app but were unable to install the app on iPhone. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPhone .

Next Steps

Please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

---

Here is the info.plist that i am submittin. Look at the key  'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities' where they say the problem is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourvoice.chatomic</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>107</string>
    <key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>f1e34e6abf0c05dfe5254ef3cc5debf97924e90b</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>KitInfo</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>KitName</key>
                <string>Crashlytics</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow to use current location?</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>OpenSans-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Semibold.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Regular.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>voip</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>ActivityIndicatorView</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>MainChatomicStoryboard</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
        <string>armv6</string>
        <string>gps</string>
        <string>location-services</string>
        <string>wifi</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key is essentially saying that install **ONLY** on devices with armv6 and armv7 processors. All devices which have arm64(iPhone 5s and above), wouldn't be able to install the app.

Comment: @Sudhir hello my application is rejected by apple becuase i have the same issue .. can you please tell me how can you solved this??

Comment: @BandishDave did you solve this? Got the same issue now

Answer (score 3):

You will want to take the `<string>armv7</string>` and `<string>armv6</string>` out.

With `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` you are saying that the app only works on devices that have the features listed. As such you're saying that you only support devices that are `armv6` and `armv7`, which is contradictory.

As a note, if your app can run without `gps` (e.g. on an iPod Touch) then you'll want to take those keys out too, only have them in there if you absolutely require them.

Comment: Do you mean that when we do not set these values it is considered as does not care. Please clarify that if i am setting both then does it mean that they both are contradiction in some way for some device(s)?

Comment: I think you have got the point there hypercrypt. I was also thinking so but this tiring process of Apple made me look for solutions. I think it should work. I would mark your answer as soon as i got success this time.